# User Registration: Creating user accounts Django 2.1.5

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-users, django-2.1

I'm having some trouble creating new accounts and then authenticating. I enter all the credentials in (username, password), and select "submit", and it successfully redirects me back to the 'account successfully created page'. However i can't find the new user account in the database and on the staff account.

This is my views file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
return render(request, 'user_example/index.html')

def register(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)


    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        raw_password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        '''user=User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=raw_password)
        user.save()'''
        user=authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        user.save()
        #if user1 is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('success')

else:
    form=UserCreationForm()


#context={'form': form}
return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})    #as

def success(request):
return render(request, 'user_example/success.html')
```

This is my success template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Successfull!</title>
</head>
    <body>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1>Congratulations {{ user.username }}!! you have successfully created an account.</h1>
        {% endif %}
            <p>You can go back to the<a href="{% url 'index' %}"> homepage 
</a>now.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my register template:

```
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}
{% block register_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>Create an Account</h3>
                    {% if error_message %}
                        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'success' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% include 'user_example/form-template.html' %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p><strong>-- OR --</strong></p>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    {% load socialaccount %}
                   <a href="{% provider_login_url 'github' %}">SignUp with Github</a>                     
                }
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Already have an account? <a href="">Click here</a> to log in.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Please help, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why did you comment out user=User.objects.create_user... ? That is the function creating and saving your user.

Comment: Because it gave the same outcome still i'm  getting now. Just added the ''success template'' code to it.. what else could be the problem?

Comment: Can you include your User model and model manager. Will need to see that create_user function. Are you calling save() within it?